# Handlebars + Meteor + iron-router

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

I am using iron-router for my meteor project and everything was going fine but I just ran into some strange behavior.

I have a loop set up for a list of items that looks something like this.

```
{{#each list_items}}
  <div>{{user.username}}
    <a href="{{link}}">Click here!</a>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

The JSON object for my user looks something like this:

```
{
  user: {
      username: jdoe
    },
  images: {
    low-res-url: http://example.com
  },
  link: http://example.com/profile
}
```

Now the {{user.username}} shows up as expected but when I try to put the {{link}} in the href I get an error from iron-router saying

```
"You called Router.path for a route named undefined but that that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it?"
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the hood Iron-Router registers handelbars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function (options) {                          
  ...
});
```

Simply change field `link` to different name like `my_link`.

Comment: Where is this officially documented? I wish I knew this earlier!

Answer (score 4):

As @perhelium mentioned Iron-Router has specified a helper named 'link'

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function (options) {...});
```

In order to access an item named 'link' in your JSON object you need to explicitly refer to the JSON object itself.

So your line: `<a href="{{link}}">Click here!</a>`

Would need to be specified as `<a href="{{this.link}}">Click here!</a>`

Comment: Thank you, this is a better solution then renaming every collection item to `my_link`.